# cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for borrow expression due to conflicting requirements

Tags: reference, rust, lifetime

```
pub struct FooStruct<'a> {
  pub bars: Vec<&'a str>,
}

pub trait FooTrait<'a> {
  fn getBars(&self) -> &'a Vec<&'a str>;
}

impl<'a> FooTrait<'a> for FooStruct<'a> {
  fn getBars(&self) -> &'a Vec<&'a str> {
    &self.bars // cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for borrow expression due to conflicting requirements
  }
}
```

Run it: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3211c32dd5b9244ff91777f1820ffed5

I do not understand where the requirement conflict comes from. Afaik there is no conflict since everything lives as long as the `FooStruct` lives.

Comment: `'a` might be *longer* than the lifetime of the `FooStruct`. Then it would be unsound to have a `&'a Vec<_>` because the `Vec` would not last for the entire `'a`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's take it apart:

```
pub struct FooStruct<'a> {
  pub bars: Vec<&'a str>,
}
```

`FooStruct` holds a container containing string slices with lifetime `'a`. The container's lifetime corresponds to the lifetime of `FooStruct`.

```
pub trait FooTrait<'a> {
  fn getBars(&self) -> &'a Vec<&'a str>;
}
```

`FooTrait` wants `getBars` to return a reference to a container holding string slices with lifetime `'a`. The lifetime of the returned reference should be `'a`, too.

```
impl<'a> FooTrait<'a> for FooStruct<'a> {
  fn getBars(&self) -> &'a Vec<&'a str> {
    &self.bars
  }
}
```

Here, `getBars` returns a reference to `self.bars` which is a container of string slices with lifetime `'a`. So far, so good.

- However, what is the lifetime of `&self.bars`? It corresponds to the lifetime of `self` (i.e. the respective `FooStruct`).
- What is the lifetime of `self`? It is `'self` (an implicit lifetime).

However, the `FooTrait` requires that the returned reference lifetime is `'a`, so that does not match `FooTrait`'s declaration.

One solution is to separate the lifetimes in `FooTrait`:

```
pub trait FooTrait<'a> {
  fn getBars<'s>(&'s self) -> &'s Vec<&'a str>;
}

impl<'a> FooTrait<'a> for FooStruct<'a> {
  fn getBars<'s>(&'s self) -> &'s Vec<&'a str> {
    &self.bars
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. My mistake was the wrong assumption that `FooStruct<'a>` or `FooTrait<'a>` implicitly binds `'a` to `self`. Now I understand that it merely informs of the existence of such lifetimes. Making the lifetime of `&self` explicit indeed solved the problem.